# Use get param in root route NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to get `GET` parameter in the root route.
I read from the docs that I need `_id.vue` file for that and I have it in the same level as 'index.vue'. In the `index.vue` I have:

```
beforeMount () {
  console.log(this.$route);
}
```

I am trying to access it with params in the URL, but `this.$route.params` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing things. `this.$route.params` is for route params e.g. _id.vue. For example lets say u have `pages/some/_id.vue` then u load url `/some/param/` and in your `$route.params` will be `id:param`.

But if u want to get `GET` param e.g.  `/some?param=value` you don't need `_id`. its just accessed via `this.$route.query`

See [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) here

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` way:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = urlParams.get('id'); // ?id=123
```

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams)